# ¿Como alinear los elementos de una matriz al imprimirla?

Tags: java

mi pregunta es cómo podría alinear los elementos de una matriz para que salgan alineados a la derecha.

[image: Ejemplo]

Este el el codigo que había hecho hasta ahora:

```
for (int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    {  
        System.out.print("|");
        for (int j=0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" " + matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("|");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Gracias por vuestra respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que algunos números son de 2 dígitos por lo que descuadra el pintado, para eso puedes usar el método `format` de la clase `String` de la siguiente manera:

```
 for (int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++)
            {  
                System.out.print("|");
                for (int j=0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
                {
                    String value = String.format("%2s", matrix[i][j]);
                    System.out.print(" " + value + " ");
                }
                System.out.print("|");
                System.out.println();
            }
```

Ten en cuenta que "%2s" le indica que muestre una cadena de hasta 2 dígitos, por lo que si tu número es de un dígito, llenara con espacio en blanco el primer dígito.

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
|  2   3  12 |
|  4   1   1 |
|  5  23   1 |
```